# How to launch Android pattern lock screen from within application

Tags: android

I want to use android pattern lock screen in my application. I want to lock the folder within my application and unlock once a user enters correct password. For this I need android pattern lock. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here is the **extracted source code** with **simple APIs** to use it in ***YOUR OWNN APP*** > **[android-lockpattern](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/)**

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find the source code that implements the pattern lock, copy it into your project, refactor it into your own package, adjust it to be a reusable component (as the existing code may only really work as the device keyguard), and then integrate it into your app.